# Using awk to replace first occurence into a new file

Tags: awk

Consider the following example:

```
[user]$ cat file.txt
double n=5;
double a=8;
double b=a*n;
```

I wish to replace the first occurence of a ( in this case the second line) and print it into a new file.

If I do:

```
[user]$ awk '/a/ {print "double a=100;";next}; 1' file.txt > newfile.txt
[user]$ cat newfile.txt
double n=5;
double a=100;
double a=100;
```

If I do:

```
[user]$ awk '/a/ {print "double a=100;"; exit}; 1' file.txt > newfile.txt
[user]$ cat newfile.txt
double n=5;
double a=100;
```

I wish to obtain:

```
[user]$ cat newfile.txt
double n=5;
double a=100;
double b=a*n;
```

ideas about how to replace the same line keeping the same structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a counter to keep track if the substitution has been done yet or not:

```
$ awk '/a/ && !c++ {print "double a=100;";next}; 1' file
double n=5;
double a=100;
double b=a*n;
```

So the first time `awk` finds `/a/` it will increment the counter in `c` to `1` and perform the action in `{ }`. Next time, `!c` will be `!1` which is False so it won't trigger `{ }`.

Comment: @jarhead see my explanation :) Is it clear? Let me know if it needs some improvement

Comment: @jarhead wrt `what does && stands for?` - you need to take an introductory programming class before trying to do any programming because if you don't know that construct that's part of [almost] all procedural languages then there's probably a whole lot of other fundamentals you also don't know.